# What is the part of speech of "going"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the *part of speech* of *going* in the following sentences?

> - I hate **going** shopping.
> - Do you like **going** sightseeing when you are on holiday?

**Update:**

> **All words** belong to categories called word classes (or **parts of speech**) according to the part they play in a sentence.
>
> The main word classes ...: Noun, Verb, Adjective, Adverb, Pronoun, Preposition, Conjunction, Determiner and Exclamation
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/word-classes-or-parts-of-speech)

I have some understanding of gerund and participle, but I don't know what they are exactly

anyway, each *part of speech* has some rules you can apply on it. so if I can determine what is the part of speech of the word then I can know how to use the rules.

as example, if the word "going" in the above sentence is *verb*, so I can change the tense of the statement by changing it. In the other hand, if it is *noun* so I can use adjectives with it ... and so on.

Assume it is Noun (compound noun), so I can add adjective to it as following:

> I hate **virtual** going shopping.

Assume it is verb, so it should be continuous tense and continuous tenses need auxiliary verb (be). So I will assume that auxiliary verb is omitted. and I can change it to other tense as following.

> I hate (I am) going shopping (now). >> I hate I was going shopping and ... .

**Note:** maybe the examples and assumptions are wrong, and I have misunderstanding of some topics of English grammar, but I'm trying to find point that I can start from it.

Comment: It's a gerund-participle.

Comment: It's a **verb**, more specifically a gerund-participle.

Comment: Those gerunds are direct objects. http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm

Comment: The question was what part of speech is "going"? "Gerund" is not a part of speech. "Going" is a verb.

Comment: I would like to coin the phrase "noun-verb duality". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality

Comment: @JavaLatte - But [verbing weirds language!](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25)